# how to display wordpress blog post categories in external html/php website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to display wordpress blog post categories in a html/php website.
This is my code.

```
<select class="form-control" name="Category">
        <option>Select Option</option>
     <?php
        include('blog/wp-load.php');  
        $category_list = wp_get_post_categories();
 
        foreach($category_list as $category){ ?>
        <option><?php echo $category->category_name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Its not working. What is wrong with my code? Is this the right method?
Can anyone please help me with the solution?

Comment: Do you want to fetch all categories or just a one post categories ?

Comment: Please clarify "not working." Does it result in an error message or does the page not load at all?

Comment: @GautamGolakiya I want to fetch all categories which are published

Comment: @slasky Page loads.. but doesn't show categories.. Also shows this error "Unable to open /home/website/public_html/blog/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_get_post_categories()` require `post_id` to render data of post if you don't pass post id wordpress get `post_id` from global `$post` object. In your case you are including wordpress outside of it's scope so this function never work.

Use `get_terms()` to get term of your taxonomy.

```
include('blog/wp-load.php');
$category_list = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
?>
if( !empty( $category_list ) && !is_wp_error( $category_list ) ){
    ?>
    <select class="form-control" name="Category">
        <option>Select Option</option>
        <?php foreach( $category_list as $category ){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

Although I do not recommend this method instead of this you can call WordPress API endpoint to get your taxonomy. You can refer [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/)

Comment: Above code is working.. Thanks a lot.. Since I am new to wordpress, I don't know much about wordpress api call.. It would be a big help if u could tell me how to call api for displaying categories.